# How to use previous versions of g++

Tags: c++, gcc

I am currently running a debian Jessy whose g++'s version is 4.9. For some reason I need to compile a code in g++-4.7 or previous version.

I got the files of gcc-4.7 and g++-4.7 from a debian wheezy of a friend who has g++-4.7.

I tried to make the apt-get install, it seemed to have worked for the gcc but not for the g++. I put the files in the /bin, but he doesn't seem to locate the g++-4.7 package.

When I try to compile my code I specify g++-4.7 but get the error : 
g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Any idea how to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to add the wheezy repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then install g++-4.7 using apt-get. Using this method you will also get bugfixes etc.

I guess, currently you're just having dependency Problems. These will be solved when you use apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to install gcc from sources. Remember that you have also to use a binutils version which maps to the gcc version. Mostly it is possible to run older gcc versions on actual binutils, but I have also seen a problem during install.

I have installed a long list of gcc versions in /opt/

Simply copy an older gcc version somewhere in the file system can result in problems with using the correct library versions.

If you install different gcc versions and also the related libraries e.g.libstdc++ , don't forget to update your library data base ( ldconfig/LD_LIBRARY_PATH/...) Maybe http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html can help.